# Unable to place Bool value in a toggle in swiftui

Tags: xcode, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

Hey all I have been trying to fix this issue for 2 days now and just can't seem to get what I am lookinhg for.

My working code:

```
struct User: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let isOn: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var users = [User]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(users, id: \.name) { item in
                HStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) {
                        Label {
                            Text(item.description)
                        } icon: {
                            //list.img
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(7)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://-----.---/jsontest.json") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                
                if let decodedResponse = try?
                    decoder.decode([User].self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = decodedResponse
                    }
                    
                    return
                }
            }
            
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

the Json its pulling looks like this:

```
{
   "name": "J",
   "description": "Echo Show",
   "isOn": true
},...
```

Like I said above this code works **as-is**. Where the problem I am having comes into play is the toggle part. It doesn't seem to be happens with the **item.isOn** for seeing if its **true** or **false**. The only thing it likes is the **.constant()**. Naturally this will not work for my case due to me needing to change the toggles to either true or false.

If it's anything other than **.constant** it has the **error** of:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding'

I can perhaps if I do this

```
@State var ison = false

var body: some View {
    List{
        ForEach(users, id: \.name) { item in
            HStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $ison)) {
```

That seems to take that error away.... but how can it get the value thats looping for isOn that way?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Pease update to be a [mcve] - I'm assuming `loaData()` isn't anything to do with the problem you're seeing?

Comment: @AshleyMills No, getting the json works just fine.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Comment: `.constant` should never be used outside of previews, the link above will give you valuable insight into SwiftUI and a solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach, making `isOn` a `var` in `User`, and using `bindings`, the `$` in the `ForEach` and `Toggle`, works for me:

```
struct User: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let description: String
    var isOn: Bool  // <-- here
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var users = [User]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach($users, id: \.name) { $item in   // <-- here
                HStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: $item.isOn) {  // <-- here
                        Label {
                            Text(item.description)
                        } icon: {
                            //list.img
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(7)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://-----.---/jsontest.json") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                if let decodedResponse = try?
                    decoder.decode([User].self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = decodedResponse
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to have put me where I needed to be, thanks!